# How to add a margin to a fixed div/footer? - HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div on the screen have a margin n the top, since it's a fixed element, I don't think it can. Also I added a `bottom: 0` to it. But I need to space it from the main elements to make my site look better. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Use `margin-top`, `padding-top` both will work.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question, you just need to use `margin-top: #;`.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to create a parent of the element. I then apply the fixed properties to the parent. I can then style the main element as much as I like. Eg.

CSS

```
    #parent{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    }
    #element{
    width:500px;
    margin:30px auto;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="parent">
       <div id="element">All the content</div
    </div>
```